# How to disable automatically showing the inspector window in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, inspector

When i hide the inspector window (normally shown on the right side of Xcode) and hover to the right edge of the Xcode Window, the inspector window automatically slides in. How can i prevent xcode from doing this and hide the inspector window permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a normal behavior when you use Xcode in full screen mode. If you do not want the inspector to appear on hover, don't use full screen mode. (If you don't like this feature, file an enhancement request with Apple.)

Comment: Thank you for your information.
I did not know that this is a normal behavior in fullscreen mode. This is very annoying, when connected to a mac using VNC and move the mouse out of the window on the right side. It also dose not "shrink" the editor, it is overlapping it.

Comment: Yes I know how it behaves! :)

Comment: You're using Xcode via VNC? That's amazing.

Comment: I share my monitor setup with two computers at the same time. I know it is not the best solution but it works. :)

Comment: I think it's very cool. The fact that a complicated app like Xcode works acceptably via screen sharing is what amazes me!

Comment: Yes it is. :) I wrote an enhancement request now on apples feedback service. ;)

Comment: @gegy Can you please share the link for the request?

Comment: @acmpo6ou I don't think that there is a possibility to share the request but if it helps here ist the request number: FB9849912